# Add blank rows or header between unique values in Sort

Tags: google-apps-script

I am pulling data from tabs in a sheet and putting them into a single tab using "compilation.sort(6,true);"

It pulls the data in, but it would be fantastic if there was a way to add rows during the sort, instead of afterwards. Is there a way to insert rows, or even a header, between unique values of the sort?

I have tried: "compilation.sort(6,true).insertRowAfter(i,1);" without success.

```
What I Have:

Row 1     |  Row 2 |  Row 3
---------  -------   -------
Pasta     | Sauce  |    3
Pasta     | Sauce  |    4
Pasta     | Sauce  |    5
Pizza     | Sauce  |    10
Pizza     | Sauce  |    11
Pizza     | Sauce  |    12
Spaghetti | Sauce  |    9



What I am looking for:

Row 1     |  Row 2 |  Row 3
---------  -------   -------
Pasta     | Sauce  |    3
Pasta     | Sauce  |    4
Pasta     | Sauce  |    5


Pizza     | Sauce  |    8
Pizza     | Sauce  |    11
Pizza     | Sauce  |    12


Spaghetti | Sauce  |    9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the active sheet you can use

```
function runSample2() {
  /**
   * @type {conditionCallback}
   */
  var cb;

  cb = function(row, i, values) {
    // Returns true if it's not the first row,
    // the first cell of a row does not equal one of previous row
    // and there is no an empty row before
    return (
      values[i - 1] &&
      values[i - 1][0] !== row[0] &&
      values[i - 1].join('') !== ''
    );
  };
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  insertRowBeforeByCondition_(sheet, cb);
}

function insertRowBeforeByCondition_(sheet, condition) {
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();
  var i = values.length;
  while (i-- > 0)
    if (condition(values[i], i, values)) sheet.insertRowBefore(i + 1);
  return sheet;
}
```

[image]

Based on [the snippet](https://github.com/contributorpw/google-apps-script-snippets/tree/master/snippets/spreadsheet_insert-rows-before-by-condition).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks contributorpw!

Comment: Glad to help and glad to have an opportunity share my snippets.